# want a query for searching that gives the precise output in aspect of group searching?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi to all I am stuck in searching and below 3 tables were given i.e Invoice table,service table and tax detail table for your better understanding

I need sql query for searching in below tables If I will pass parameter as taxId of tax detail table and want output as mention below.

Please guys help me out in this and suggest me a single sql query for the same and If I will get the exact query from any person I will endorse his account.

## 1) Invoice Table

```html
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Invoiceid(PK)</td><td>Client</td><td>Amount</td><td>Tax</td><td>totalamount</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td><td>abc</td><td>12500</td>
  <td>1000</td><td>13500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td><td>xyz</td><td>6280</td>
  <td>1000</td><td>7280</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td><td>mno</td><td>10000</td>
  <td>1000</td><td>11000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td><td>efg</td><td>5600</td>
  <td>400</td><td>6000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td><td>pqr</td><td>5000</td>
  <td>1000</td><td>6000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td><td>rst</td><td>3000</td>
  <td>0</td><td>3000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td><td>jkl</td><td>3800</td>
  <td>1200</td><td>5000</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

## 2) Service Table

```html
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Invoiceserviceid(PK)</td><td>Invoiceid(FK)</td>
  <td>Serviceid</td><td>Amount</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td><td>1</td>
  <td>12</td><td>8000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td><td>1</td>
  <td>16</td><td>4500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td><td>2</td>
  <td>17</td><td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td><td>2</td>
  <td>22</td><td>1100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td><td>2</td>
  <td>36</td><td>2200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td><td>2</td>
  <td>46</td><td>1980</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td><td>3</td>
  <td>75</td><td>10000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td><td>4</td>
  <td>69</td><td>2500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>9</td><td>4</td>
  <td>88</td><td>3600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>10</td><td>5</td>
  <td>89</td><td>5000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>11</td><td>6</td>
  <td>90</td><td>2000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>12</td><td>6</td>
  <td>15</td><td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>13</td><td>7</td>
  <td>32</td><td>3800</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

## 3) TAX Details Table

```html
<table border=1>
<tr><td>taxdetailid(PK)</td><td>Invoiceid(FK)</td>
  <td>taxid</td><td>Taxname</td>
  <td>taxamount</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
  <td>GST</td><td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
  <td>CGST</td><td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  <td>SGST</td><td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td><td>3</td><td>1</td>
  <td>GST</td><td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td><td>3</td><td>2</td>
  <td>CGST</td><td>250</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
  <td>SGST</td><td>250</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td><td>4</td><td>1</td>
  <td>GST</td><td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td><td>4</td><td>3</td>
  <td>SGST</td><td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>9</td><td>5</td><td>2</td>
  <td>CGST</td><td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>10</td><td>7</td><td>1</td>
  <td>GST</td><td>1200</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

## OUT PUT

Pass Parameter 'Taxid' of tax details table

```html
Pass Parameter value (1)
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Invoiceid</td><td>Client</td><td>Serviceid</td><td>Serviceamount</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td><td>12</td><td>8000</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td><td>16</td><td>4500</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>jkl</td><td>32</td><td>3800</td>
</tr>
</table>

Pass Parameter value (2,3)

<table border=1>
<tr><td>Invoiceid</td><td>Client</td><td>Serviceid</td><td>Serviceamount</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>xyz</td><td>17</td><td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>xyz</td><td>22</td><td>1100</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>xyz</td><td>36</td><td>2200</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>xyz</td><td>46</td><td>1980</td>
</tr>
</table>


Pass Parameter value (NULL)

<table border=1>
<tr><td>Invoiceid</td><td>Client</td><td>Serviceid</td><td>Serviceamount</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>rst</td><td>90</td><td>2000</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>rst</td><td>15</td><td>1000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also pass

1. parameter (1,2,3) result invoiceid (3)
2. parameter (2) result invoiceid (5)
3. Parameter (1,3) result invoiceid (4)

Comment: What's the logic between parameter  and result invoiceid ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, are you able to supply your data with DDL and in a consumable format? HTML tables can't be rad by SQL Server, so we can't test with that.

Comment: thanks for your interest. i have urgent requirement for solve my problem. i have join all three tables and pass the parameter. ''i.e select * from tbl_taxdetail where tbl_taxdetail.taxid in (1,3)''. this is sample query i pass this type of parameter and give output of all.